# Google map API v3: load huge polygon (region boundary)

Tags: google-maps-api-3, polygon

I am working this issue: loading huge polygon on google map API v3. It is administrative boundary of a country or a region, that's why it is huge, a lot of vertices. I have tried 02 options:

1. Draw the polygon from the defined paths: this is very slow
2. Using google FusionTableLayer, this is fast, the problem is that in certain cases Google's boundary data is not correct or insufficient and I want to use my own data. Is it possible to tweak Google FusionTableLayer to get data from my own source. E.g some pseudo-code like this:

```
var layer = new google.maps.FusionTableLayer(tableid, options);
layer.setData(owndata); // instead of layer.setQuery(query) to get data from Google
```

Is it possible to do this hack? Can anyone give me a tip? Thank you very much.

Code excerpt:

```
var paths=[]; 

var vlist=[.............]; //long list of lon,lat saved in .txt file which may size up to 1.3 Mb 

for(var j=vlist.length-1;j>0;j-=2){ 
paths.push(new google.maps.LatLng(vlist[j],vlist[j-1])) 
} 

var poly = new google.maps.Polygon({paths:paths,...}); 

poly.setMap(mymap); 
thePolygons.push(poly); 

//more polygons, some sparse areas with a lot of islands, the number of polygons may run to 1000
```

//....

Comment: Could't you create your own Fusion Table : http://www.google.com/fusiontables/Home/

Comment: Thank you for your hint. The thing is I don't want to do this manually, as I am going to have a lot of data for each country. Best is to find a way to display a huge polygon with high performance. it stucks at the moment.

Comment: 1. Show us some code - 2. Stop using Internet Explorer. Large polygons load fine in real browsers. ;-)3. If you want to load many large polygons you should look at building custom tiles: http://maps.forum.nu/v3/gm_customTiles.html (check 'Density')

Comment: My code goes like this:

var paths=[];

var vlist=[.............]; //long list of lon,lat saved in .txt file which may size up to 1.3 Mb

for(var j=vlist.length-1;j>0;j-=2){
paths.push(new google.maps.LatLng(vlist[j],vlist[j-1]))
}

var poly = new google.maps.Polygon({paths:paths,...});
poly.setMap(mymap);

thePolygons.push(poly);

//more polygons, some sparse areas with a lot of islands, the number of polygons may run to 1000

Comment: please edit your question to add the code.  You can format it in a way that is actually useful if you do that.

Comment: Seems google map visualization is another option. Can anyone give me a hint on how to do this using visualization? Thank you.

Comment: I still don't understand your question (particularly if @billy's post didn't help), the posted code isn't very useful (although now at least we can read it).  A FusionTablesLayer (or a KmlLayer) is going to render more efficiently for lots of vertices than a native polygon unless you need to have mouseovers or modify it.  The Google Visualization library has limitations, and may not work in all cases, you haven't provided enough details of your use case to tell if it will work for you.

Comment: You got it right now. Sorry for my ambiguity. That's right, I have to display huge polygons with a lot of vertices. It went well if I use FusionTableLayer, but in cases Google's data is not correct or not sufficient then I have to use my own data. And the current way is to use native polygons, which sucks. Any other way to display huge polygon effectively? That's my question. Thank you for caring.